# SQL where "something" plus "this" or "that"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that selects "something" and then select something else from a list. like, select an ambulance and then select one or more from a list.

```
select r.unit_type
from dw_prod.dbo.vw_unit_response r
where CallTypeGrp2 = 'als' 
and 
(
    r.unit_type='Ambulance' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Medic' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Engine' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Truck' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Tower' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Rescue Engine' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Brush Engine' 
    or r.unit_type = 'Paramedic Rescue Squad'
)
group by r.CADIncidentNumber
    , r.unit_type
order by r.CADIncidentNumber
```

Above is what I have so far and it works some what, but doesn't guarantee me the ambulance, which is a must. A successful query result would include:

Ambulance & Medic, Ambulance & Paramedic Tower, Ambulance & Paramedic Rescue Engine, Ambulance & ...

Comment: You should be seeing the Ambulance record as well as all the others. Perhaps there is a whitespace issue, or maybe you're using TOP 5 or something similar?

Comment: It's the sql server.

Comment: This would make more sense if ambulance was in a different column from everything else (not unit_type)

Comment: The  values are from just one table.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your query? I don't believe the `WHERE` statement provide all the necessary details. Some sample data and an expected output would help as well.

Comment: Please provide sample data of your table and expected result for it.

Comment: Rest of the code is posted.

Comment: Does data contain any records where `unit_type` = 'Ambulance' and `CallTypeGrp2` = 'als'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `in`:

```
where r.unit_type in ('Ambulance', 'Medic', 'Paramedic Engine', 'Paramedic Truck', 'Paramedic Tower', 
                      'Paramedic Rescue Engine', 'Paramedic Brush Engine', 'Paramedic Rescue Squad'
                     )
```

As an added bonus, some databases optimize in lists much better than a series of `or` comparisons.

EDIT:

Now that the question is a bit clearer, just use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select r.CADIncidentNumber, r.unit_type
from dw_prod.dbo.vw_unit_response r
where CallTypeGrp2 = 'als' and
      r.unit_type in ('Ambulance', 'Medic', 'Paramedic Engine', 'Paramedic Truck', 'Paramedic Tower', 
                          'Paramedic Rescue Engine', 'Paramedic Brush Engine', 'Paramedic Rescue Squad'
                         )
group by r.CADIncidentNumber, r.unit_type
having sum(case when r.unit_type = 'Ambulance' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
order by r.CADIncidentNumber;
```

Comment: Using `IN` is certainly cleaner, but your result set will be the same as OPs.

Comment: @KenshinH Then why dont you edit your question and show us some sample data and what you expect as outcome

Answer (score 0):

A temporary solution, where I used `unions`, but you can create a temptable or some other way to get table.

```
;with cte as (
select 'Ambulance' as unit_type union
select 'Medic' as unit_type union
select 'Paramedic Engine' as unit_type union
select 'Paramedic Truck' as unit_type 
)


select  * 
from    cte a
        left join [dbo].[OriginalTable] b on b.typeName = a.unit_type

where  b.Id is null -- for those which are not found
where  b.Id is not null -- only found
```

There are two where conditions, and you definitely will use your required one
   This query will tell you which unit_types are not available and which are available.